# Catalog price rules (discounts) disables automatically

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, discount

I have an issue with the Catalog price rules.

When I enable them, it works fine, but after few day's they desactivate automatically.

I tryed this solution:
http://creatingawebstore.com/how-to-setup-magento-cron-jobs-demonstrated-on-cpanel.html

But it didn't help...

Anyone has a clue why this is happening?

The configuration of the price rule is set to be active for a Year.

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you've linked there to a tutorial setting up cron schedule for Magento, have you checked the Magento cron is actually running?

This extension is great for checking which tasks are being run via cron and if there are issues. Try installing this free extension to check if your cron and more specifically the Catalog Price Rules task is running correctly.

https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

Also, just as a possible note, you do need to click Apply Rules after creating rules, just creating and saving rules does not necessarily apply them.

Comment: thanks for the tip.I just installed the extension and configured the Cron, so it appears correctly and working. I can see the cron jobs. The issue is (sorry for newby question) I don't see Catalog_price_rules cron or anything similar, should I set up something else or it will work? Thanks again for the help.